# Como mover un objeto a donde se toque la pantalla en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Buen dia,

Quiero obtener el punto X, Y cuando se toca la pantalla para cambiar de posicion un textview, el problema que me encuentro es que en el eje Y obtengo un desplazamiento y no puedo moverlo al punto donde se toco la pantalla

Al parecer es por el actionbar pero no se como podria obtener el ancho del actionbar para restarlo o el valor de Y sin contar la parte superior.

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        scale_gesturee?.onTouchEvent(event)

        var texto:TextView=findViewById(R.id.textView25)


        texto.text= "Posicion X:"+texto.x.toString()+",Posicion Y:"+texto.y.toString()
        return true
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien puede orientarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo consegui con estas lineas:

```
val rectangle = Rect()
        val window = window
        window.decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle)
        val statusBarHeight = rectangle.top
        val contentViewTop = window.findViewById<View>(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).top
        val titleBarHeight = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el tamaño del ActionBar, llama a sus propiedades

```
actionBar.width
actionBar.height
```

Puedes restarlos al layout o al texview haciendo los cálculos con sus propiedades de la misma manera

Así lo hago yo para detectar si el click fue en en lado izquierdo o derecho de la pantalla, obtenlo en ancho del layout y después valido la posición x del evento si es mayor o menor a la mitad.